# compressed image to image

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rosjava to write code, but now when i use pi_face_tracker, i come across problems. The input of the pi_face_tracker should be type image, but what i get form the camera is compressed image. What should i do to solve it? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35183/compressed-image-to-image/) by [han](https://answers.ros.org/users/2284/han/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [republish](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport#republish) node to convert the transport from compressed to raw. Your call will look something like this:

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=(in_base_topic) raw out:=(out_base_topic)
```

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [han](https://answers.ros.org/users/2284/han/) on 2012-05-30**:
I don't know what class i can use for this in rosjava, can you help me on it?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-31**:
@han: I am not sure if I understand your question. You cannot call this in code from Java. It is a C++ binary. You should run it as a node alongside pi_face_tracker.

**Comment by [jorgelc79](https://answers.ros.org/users/2528/jorgelc79/) on 2015-05-14**:
How could I include this rosrun inside of a launch file?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is an old question, but if somebody is looking for how to do this in a launch file the answer is here: http://answers.ros.org/question/12216/launch-file-how-to-write-it/

the code is:

```
<node name="republish" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=/axis_camera raw out:=/axis_camera/image_raw" />
```

---

Originally posted by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) with karma: 153 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9